# How do I debug a failing additional Dockerfile?

Tags: ddev

I have created `.ddev/web-build/Dockerfile`. It builds, but it doesn't do what I want. How do I figure out why? `DRUD_DEBUG=1 ddev start` doesn't show any additional output. I don't know the proper `docker-compose` command to try building it manually either. This does not work:

```
cd .ddev
docker-compose build web
```

because it needs specific environment variables that DDEV injects.

Comment: When a .ddev/web-build/Dockerfile build fails in any way, it shows the failure output. I guess it's not failing for you... So please try this: `cd .ddev/web-build; docker build .` and see if that works to build an image for you, and you can experiment with that image.

Comment: Can you share more details? It could help to see the Dockerfile you've created, and get a better explanation about what exactly is not working

Comment: I don't remember at this point :) it was more a question of how to see the actual build output when ddev does the building, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to see the build is `ddev debug refresh`, which will show you the whole build as it happens, with nothing cached.

You can also do the same thing manually:

```
cd .ddev
~/.ddev/bin/docker-compose -f .ddev-docker-compose-full.yaml build web --no-cache
```

and you'll see the full build go by. You can use additional build arguments as well to change the output format, etc. For example, `~/.ddev/bin/docker-compose -f .ddev-docker-compose-full.yaml build web --no-cache --progress=plain`

You can review the entire Dockerfile that's being built at .ddev/.webimageBuild/Dockerfile.

See [docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/customizing-images/#debugging-the-dockerfile-build).